# DISM could not find Install.esd file in Windows

Tags: windows

I'm trying to repair my `Windows`. `DISM` could not find a `install` file to repair the data. So I downloaded new `windows.iso` installer with `windows installer tool`, mounted it to `F:` driver with `Daemon Tool` and tried to execute this command:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:ESD:F:\sources\install.esd:1 /LimitAccess
```

But `DISM` complaining that could not find `Source` file in this path...

I have this error in japanese, but here it is

```
エラー: 0x800f081f

ソース ファイルが見つかりませんでした。
機能の復元に必要なファイルの場所を指定するには、"Source" オプションを使用してください。ソースの場所の指定方法の詳細については、https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077 を参照してくだ さい。
```

But the path is right.
I also tried to copy it to `D:`, create `mount` dir mount it and give it that path, but the result was same... what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:F:\sources\Install.WIM:1 /limitaccess`.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but this just spammed all windows folders to my `D` drive and the same error appeared